# Why isn't Font Awesome loading in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, font-awesome

Font Awesome icons are miserably failing to load on [this website](https://archify.com/), in all versions of IE (it shows up perfectly in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera). I'm supposedly loading IE7+ support for Font Awesome on the following conditional IE statement:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css_archify/font-awesome-ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

I'm loading the default Font Awesome CSS in between both, just to make sure `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements get supported before being used in any of the following stylesheets. Any ideas why these icons are not showing up on IE?

Comment: did you read this: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/38

Comment: Yes, I'm targeting IE7 as explained above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the **script errors** prior to check the CSS from Font-Awesome, I know that Font-Awesome do not load correct in Quirks Mode, but **it's IE7** and it uses a mix of CSS rules and javascript.

In IE7, if you have one javascript line that throws an error, it will stop executing the rest of the code.

[image]

Give yourself a test, create a blank page with just some Font-Awesome icons, and no javascript plugins whatsoever and see if it loads there correctly.

Comment: Thanks, @balexandre. I'll fix those script errors later today. You mentioned IE7 stops executing the code whenever it finds an error in the code: so even though this may be the cause for the icons not showing up in IE7, it doesn't apply to the later versions (IE 8, 9 & 10), right?

Comment: Also, the error is most likely from one of the JavaScript files included right before `</body>`, while Font Awesome is being loaded within `<head>`. Aw man, this is so weird.